# "Operand types do not match" when storing AH into a DW variable

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Hey guys i'm having a bit of a problem with a an assembly code

Lines 55,60 Operand types do not match
Am i trying to move 16 bit memory into 8 bit or other way around? if so how do i fix my issue? thank you!

```
; NUM%
;
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 100h
    .DATA
Ten         DW 10
Two         DW 2
Num         DW 0  ; variable to save Num input from user 
Dig         DW 0  ; Variable to save Dig input from user
Half_Dig    DW 0  ; Variable to save Dig/2
Result      DW 0  ; Variable to store result  from Num^2%dig
PromptStr1  DB 13,10,'Please Enter Number (from 00 up to 99)',13,10,'$';string output to user
PromptStr2  DB 13,10,'Please Enter Digit (from 0 up to 9)',13,10,'$' ;string output to user 
ResultStr   DB 13,10,'XX^2 mod X = X',13,10,'$';Result output to user
ResultStr1  DB 13,10,'The result shloud be round up',13,10,'$'
ResultStr2  DB 13,10,'The result shloud be round down',13,10,'$'
DivisionErr DB 13,10,'Division Error',13,10,'$'

            .CODE             
           MOV AX,@DATA
           MOV DS,AX
           MOV AH,9
           MOV DX,OFFSET PromptStr1
           INT 21h
           ;  Reading First Part of Num
           MOV AH,1
           INT 21h
           MOV ResultStr[2],AL
           SUB AL,'0'
           MOV AH,0
           MUL Ten
           MOV Num,AX
           MOV AX,0
           ;  Reading Second Part of Num
           MOV AH,1
           INT 21h
           MOV ResultStr[3],AL
           SUB AL,'0'
           MOV AH,0
           ADD Num,AX
           MOV AH,0
           ; Reading Dig
           MOV AH,1
           INT 21h
           MOV ResultStr[11],AL
           SUB AL,'0'
           MOV AH,0
           MOV Dig,AX
           MOV AX,0
           ; checking to see if dig==0 , if so divsion error
           CMP Dig,0
           JE Error
           MOV AX,Dig
           DIV Two
           ***MOV Half_Dig,AH***
           MOV AX,0
           MOV AX,Num
           MUL Num
           DIV Half_dig
           ***MOV Result, AH***
```

Would appreciate helping what i'm doing wrong here!

Comment: I'd suggest to define `Half_Dig` and `Result` as `DB` instead of `DW`; you seem to be using only 8 bits there, so why define them as 16 bits?

Comment: So db holds a number between 0-9, considered 1 bite?

Comment: A byte is 8 bits on x86 (like all modern ISAs), so it can hold values from 0..255.  (Or if you interpret it as signed,  -128..+127).  Of course if you're reading an ASCII character, that takes one byte, and if we're talking about base 10 then a single-digit string can only be `'0' .. '9'`

Answer (score 1):

### Pinpointing the problems

> ```
>   MOV AX,@DATA
>   MOV DS,AX
>   MOV AH,9
>   MOV DX,OFFSET PromptStr1
>   INT 21h
>   ;  Reading First Part of Num
>   MOV AH,1
>   INT 21h
>   MOV ResultStr[2],AL
>   SUB AL,'0'
>   MOV AH,0
> ? MUL Ten                           Does not need the WORD sized multiplication
>   MOV Num,AX
> ? MOV AX,0                          Redundant
>   ;  Reading Second Part of Num
>   MOV AH,1
>   INT 21h
>   MOV ResultStr[3],AL
>   SUB AL,'0'
>   MOV AH,0
>   ADD Num,AX
> ? MOV AH,0                          Redundant
>   ; Reading Dig
>   MOV AH,1
>   INT 21h
>   MOV ResultStr[11],AL
>   SUB AL,'0'
>   MOV AH,0
>   MOV Dig,AX
> ? MOV AX,0                         Redundant
>   ; checking to see if dig==0 , if so divsion error
>   CMP Dig,0
>   JE Error
>   MOV AX,Dig
> ? DIV Two                          WORD sized division requiring DX=0
> ? ***MOV Half_Dig,AH***            Quotient is in AL instead
> ? MOV AX,0                         Redundant
>   MOV AX,Num
>   MUL Num
>   DIV Half_dig                     Danger! Half_dig could be zero
> ? ***MOV Result, AH***             Quotient is in AX instead
> ```

What your code needs most is defining the variables as **bytes**

```
Ten         DB 10
Num         DB 0  ; 0-99
Dig         DB 0  ; 0-9
Half_Dig    DB 0  ; 1-4
Result      DB 0  ; 0-3
```

And then you need to be clear about what you want to calculate. Your message says : `XX^2 mod X` but your program tries to calculate `XX^2 mod (X/2)`. Which is it?

In below code I will go with the *Half_Dig* approach...

### Applying these changes

```
  MOV AX,@DATA
  MOV DS,AX
  MOV AH,9
  MOV DX,OFFSET PromptStr1
  INT 21h
  ;  Reading First Part of Num
  MOV AH,1
  INT 21h
  MOV ResultStr[2],AL
  SUB AL,'0'
  MUL Ten
  MOV Num,AL
  ;  Reading Second Part of Num
  MOV AH,1
  INT 21h
  MOV ResultStr[3],AL
  SUB AL,'0'
  ADD Num,AL
  ; Reading Dig
  MOV AH,1
  INT 21h
  MOV ResultStr[12],AL
  SUB AL,'0'
  MOV Dig,AL

  ; checking to see if (dig/2)==0 , if so divsion error
  SHR AL, 1
  JZ Error
  MOV Half_Dig, AL
  MOV AL, Num
  MUL AL
  DIV Half_dig
  MOV Result, AL
```

You don't need a division to divide by 2. A simple `SHR` does a better job.

This uses: `ResultStr   DB 13,10,'XX^2 mod (X/2) = X',13,10,'$'`